# How to split comma, semicolon and comma separated phrases with semicolons around?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, typescript

How to split comma, semicolon and comma separated phrases with semicolons around where it should treat anything between semicolons with a comma as the delimiter, but also delimit just comma and semicolon all together in funcion?

String of words:

```
var words = "apple;banana;apple, banana;fruit"
```

Regex function separate by , and ;

```
 var result = words.split(/[,;]+/);
```

Result from that function is:

```
[ "apple", "banana", "apple", " banana", "fruit" ]
```

But what I am looking to get is this, to have "banana, apple" and treat it as a separate value

```
[ "apple", "banana, apple", " banana", "fruit" ]
```

So is it possible to combine 2 cases in that function to output as the second example? Or maybe some other elegant way?

Comment: In your wnted result there is `"banana, apple"` - it is correct? I dont get why - can you explain and give more examples?

Comment: Wouldn't you just want `words.split(';')`?

Comment: Why `"banana, apple"` in your desired result is one string-  can you explain the rule and give another example?

Comment: updated example two

Comment: @AlexFF1 you aple-bana secodn example dont match first example - in first you have element `"banana, apple"` but in second you have `"apple, banana"`

Comment: Alex, it's profoundly unclear what you're asking, as your examples exhibit different behavior from one another and from your title question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of match and replace can be used.

With the match we take the two patterns we have

1. Values between delimiter `(?:\w+;\w+,)`
2. Value not in between delimiter `\w+;?`

Now based on matched group we just change the values in desired format using replace

```js
let words = `apple;banana;apple, banana;fruit`

let op = words.match(/(?:\w+;\w+,)|\w+;?/g)
              .map(e=>e.replace(/(?:(\w+);(\w+),)|(\w+);?/g, (m,g1,g2,g3)=> g1 ? g1+', '+g2 : g3 ))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: what about this scenario "apple;banana;apple, banana;fruit, orange"..?

Comment: @AlexFF1 what ? can you explain what you're talking about ? what is expected output in this particular case ?

Answer (score 0):

Array math is easier than regex.

## Objective

`apple;banana;apple, banana;fruit` > `[ "apple", "banana, apple", " banana", "fruit" ]`

Remove spaces, split at `;`, split at `,`.

## Solution

```js
const words = 'apple;banana;apple, banana;fruit';
const result = words.split(' ').join('').split(';').join(',').split(',');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to treat anything between semicolons with comma as a separate value

Comment: @AlexFF1 I think the common struggle with all of the answers and comments is that we cannot decipher what you *mean* as "treat anything between semicolons with comma as a separate value" - it is not obvious from your example(s) or comments. You apparently want to split by semicolons *except* when there's a comma, then change the previous semicolon into a comma and treat the comma as a semicolon. ??

Answer (score 0):

Accorting to question apple-banana second example (after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55403175/5) question update) try

```
words.split(';');
```

```js
var words = "apple;banana;apple, banana;fruit"

var result = words.split(';');

console.log(result);
```